# Why are these triangles & their circumcircles collinear upon inversion?

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, inverse, curves, tiling

Consider an arbitrary logarithmic spiral of growth rate $q$ per angle $\theta$ and flair coefficient $b=\ln q/\theta$. Plot the spiral $z=e^{(b+i)\theta}$ and mark off the points that are equally spaced in $\theta$. Connect the points sequentially and build out isosceles triangles of vertex angle $\theta$ from each line segment. See the figure below for some examples.

I find that all the triangles and their circumscribed circles are collinear upon inversion, say $w=1/z^*$ where $z$ is either a triangle or circle.

I understand that circles can be mapped to straight lines by Möbius transform, but I don't understand how that translates to this problem. This one transform that I found, namely,

$$w=\frac{iz+i}{-z+1}$$

did not seem to work. Moreover, it is not equal to $1/z^*$. But more to the point, what makes the logarithmic spiral gnomons have this property?

[image: Log spirals and triangles]

Comment: I read only the title and i wonder how can triangles be collinear?

Comment: @Aqua The title says collinear upon *inversion*. Thanks for looking.

Comment: No inverson takes triangle to a point!

Comment: And how can circles or their images be collinear?

Comment: @Aqua Yes-that's exactly the point. Circles mostly map to circles, but not here. They *can* map to lines. So the question is what is it about this logarithmic problem that renders it so. Also, the inversion doesn't take the triangle to a point. The *three* points are collinear.

Comment: How can lines be collinear?

Comment: Do you mean that after you invert, the circumcircles all turn into lines (which are necessarily *concurrent* at the center of inversion) and therefore the three vertices of each triangle become three collinear points?

Comment: @MishaLavrov Yes, that's it. Call the triangle Z and the circle C. I find that $1/C^*$ is a straight line and that $1/Z^*$ is three points on that line (as you would expect).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saying that your circles are transformed into straight lines by an inversion with center (pole) $O$ is equivalent to say that your circles are passing through the origin.

Therefore, the issue is reduced to establish that the origin belongs to the circumscribed circles to the isoceles triangles ; this is a rather simple consequence of the inscribed angle theorem as we can see on the figure below better than with words.

Besides, on your figures, especially the second one, we see a discrete approximation of the **evolute** of the spiral (itself a spiral) defined either as the envelope of its normals or as the locus of centers of curvature. This could constitute another approach to your issue.

[image]

Comment: Brilliant. I added plots of the circumcircles and they all passed through the origin. Thanks.