# Constructing n tangential arcs given a start point, end point and n radii

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles, parametric

A line starts at $A=(x_s, y_s)$ and finishes at $B=(x_e,y_e)$

Some things we know about this line:

- It is made up of $n$ circular arcs that are tangential to one another where they join together.
- Every arc is upwards facing (like a smile)
- The arcs have radii $R_1, R_2, ...$ etc. that we know the value of
- We can assume $x_s < x_e$ and $y_s < y_e$
- The gradient of the line at the start point $A$ of the line is zero, at the end point $B$ the gradient can be whatever

My aim is to be able to sketch this line, and to do that I expect this problem reduces to finding the $n$ center points $(x_{c1},y_{c1}), (x_{c2},y_{c2}), ...$etc. and the $n-1$ tangential points $(x_{t1},y_{t1}), (x_{t2},y_{t2}), ...$etc. but I keep getting stuck when I try to do that myself.

If finding the general solution to this is too tricky, any answer for $n=2$ or $n=3$ would still be very helpful. My end goal is to write some code that sketches the required line given (start point, end point, radii) as an input.

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that 2 circular arcs AB and BC (with centers on $C_1$ and $C_2$) with B as their "point of connection" have a common tangent if and only the $C_1,C_2,B) are aligned ?

Comment: yes, I tried to use that in one of the attempts I made of solving this but I couldn't find a constructive use of it. I don't know if I'm missing something obvious or this problem is just harder than I thought it would be. I'm pretty sure a solution must exist though - but if someone can show me actually a unique solution doesn't exist that would be useful too.

Comment: A unique solution can exist for $n=2$. But for $n\ge3$ you have $n$ unknowns $\theta_1,\dots \theta_n$ and $2$ equations for the coordinates of $B$, hence I expect infinitely many solutions to exist.

Comment: Select any point out different than A and B that allows you to run any number of rays between them. Draw an arc between the ray through the A and the "closest" arc to the A-arc, tangent to the two rays. Any arc will work. Now draw an arc tangent at the tangent in the closest ray and the first arc that is also tangent at the first and second ray closest to A-ray. And so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can set WLOG $A=(0,0)$. Hence $C_1=(0,R_1)$ and (see figure below):
$$
\begin{align}
C_2 =\ & C_1+(R_1-R_2)\big(\sin\theta_1,-\cos\theta_1\big)\\
C_3 =\ & C_2+(R_2-R_3)\big(\sin(\theta_1+\theta_2),-\cos(\theta_1+\theta_2)\big)\\
\dots & \\
\end{align}
$$
$$
\begin{align}
T_1 =\ & C_1+R_1\big(\sin\theta_1,-\cos\theta_1\big)\\
T_2 =\ & C_2+R_2\big(\sin(\theta_1+\theta_2),-\cos(\theta_1+\theta_2)\big)\\
T_3 =\ & C_3+R_3\big(\sin(\theta_1+\theta_2+\theta_3),
-\cos(\theta_1+\theta_2+\theta_3)\big)\\
\dots & \\
\end{align}
$$
where $\theta_i$ is the angle insisting on the $i$th arc.

As $T_n= B$ we must then satisfy two equations: $T_{nx}=x_e$ and $T_{ny}=y_e$ for the $n$ unknowns $\theta_1,\dots\theta_n$.

For $n=2$ Mathematica finds an explicit (but very lengthy) solution. For $n>2$ one could in principle find a solution depending on $n-2$ angles among  $\theta_i$.

[image]

Comment: [+1] Very good answer, involving a kind of discrete evolute, reminding me a past question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3678329/305862)

Comment: This is such a nice way of thinking about the problem! It's exactly the sort of thing I was looking for thank you!